# Trying to create diagonal patterns using graphics

Tags: python, graphics

I am trying to create a diagonal pattern using graphics, but only half of the pattern is filled. I am also trying to make it so that the same pattern fills the whole 500x500 but have no idea how.
EDIT: Sorry I don't mean all of it filled, like from (0-100,500) has the line pattern and then the (100-200,500) is empty and so on.

```
from graphics import *

def patchwork():
    win = GraphWin('Lines test',500,500)
    for x in range(0,101,20):
        line = Line(Point(x,0), Point(100,100-x))
        line.setFill('red')
        line.draw(win)

     for x2 in range(101,0,-20):
        line2 = Line(Point(100,0+x2), Point(x2,100))
        line2.setFill('red')
        line2.draw(win)
```

I expected the pattern to fully fill the 100x100 with diagonal lines but only have of it is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by drawing four sets of lines inside a single `for` loop, as shown below. The code is written in terms of the window size `L`, so that it can be easily changed if needed.

```
from graphics import *

def patchwork():
    L = 500;
    win = GraphWin('Lines test',L,L)
    for s in range(0,L+1,20):
        line1 = Line(Point(s,0), Point(L,L-s))
        line1.setFill('red')
        line1.draw(win)

        line2 = Line(Point(L,s), Point(s,L))
        line2.setFill('red')
        line2.draw(win)

        line3 = Line(Point(s,L), Point(0,L-s))
        line3.setFill('red')
        line3.draw(win)

        line4 = Line(Point(0,s), Point(s,0))
        line4.setFill('red')
        line4.draw(win)
```

---

**Updated code** to generate a piecewise pattern:

```
from graphics import *

def patchwork():
    L = 500;
    W = 100;
    f = L/W;
    win = GraphWin('Lines test',L,L)
    for xL in [0,200,400]:
      xR = xL + W;
      for s in range(0,W+1,20):
          line1 = Line(Point(xL + s,0), Point(xL,f*s))
          line1.setFill('red')
          line1.draw(win)

          line2 = Line(Point(xL + s,0), Point(xR,L - f*s))
          line2.setFill('red')
          line2.draw(win)

          line3 = Line(Point(xL + s,L), Point(xL,L - f*s))
          line3.setFill('red')
          line3.draw(win)

          line4 = Line(Point(xL + s,L), Point(xR,f*s))
          line4.setFill('red')
          line4.draw(win)
```

Comment: Oh thank you for answering the question.I am sorry, because what I was meant to say was how to make the first (0-100,500) collum line pattern and then the (100-200,500) collum to be empty

Comment: When you say (0-100, 500) do you mean the rectangular area from x = 0 to x = 100 and y = 0 to y = 500?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant sorry

Comment: And then do you want to continue that on/off pattern? I mean does (200-300) have the pattern, (300-400) is empty, and (400-500) have the pattern?

Comment: Yes just like that

Comment: See the updated code, which uses another for loop to generate the on/off pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I was wondering if there was a way to make the lines a bit more slanted?